# Can you guys point out where i do wrong error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '20200427151140'

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @PathFolder varchar(255)
DECLARE @FullPathFolder varchar(255)
DECLARE @FileName varchar(255)
DECLARE @QUERY nVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @UNAME VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PASSW VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @FileId varchar(20)
DECLARE @Today AS datetime
DECLARE @Active AS varchar(50)
DECLARE @termin AS varchar(50)
DECLARE @FlagGenerate AS varchar(1)

SET @UNAME = ''
SET @PASSW = ''
SET @PathFolder = ''
SET @Active = 'Active'
SET @termin = 'Terminate'

--SET @Today = '2019-10-02'
--SET @Today = dateadd(month,5,getdate())
SET @Today = getdate()

SET @FileId = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Today, 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @Today, 8),':','')
SET @Today = CAST(@today AS date)
SET @FlagGenerate = '0' --' 0 = Generate Difference; 1 = All
SELECT @FileId

--==================== AKTIF =================
SET @FileName = 'DATA.LOCK.PBK.AKTIF_' + @FileId + '.dat'
SET @FullPathFolder = @PathFolder+'\'+@FileName
--SET @command = @command + ' ''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @tanggal,121) + ''''' '



   SET @QUERY = 'SELECT lat.Custcode, lat.NoRekDebet, Format(lat.TotalLockAmount, ''#0'') TotalLockAmount FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Id = ''''' + @FileId + ''''' and lat.LockStatus = ''active'' '
SET @QUERY = 'bcp "'+@QUERY+'" queryout '+@FullPathFolder+' -U '+@UNAME+' -P '+@PASSW+' /S '+@@SERVERNAME+' -t"~" -T -c'
SET @QUERY = 'execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell '+''''+@QUERY+''''

    SELECT @QUERY

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY
```

I got this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '20200427151140'

When I delete the condition

```
lat.Id = ''''' + @FileId + '''''
```

I think there is problem with how I wrote the expression.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue of quotes in `'#0'` and `'acitve'`:

try the following:

```
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT lat.Custcode, lat.NoRekDebet, Format(lat.TotalLockAmount, ''''#0'''') TotalLockAmount FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Id = ''''' + @FileId + ''''' and lat.LockStatus = ''''active'''' '
SET @QUERY = 'bcp "'+@QUERY+'" queryout '+@FullPathFolder+' -U '+@UNAME+' -P '+@PASSW+' -S '+@@SERVERNAME+' -t"~" -T -c'
SET @QUERY = 'execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell '+''''+@QUERY+''''

    print @QUERY
```